# Unable to resolve $(Release.ReleaseId) in Azure DevOps yml pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

When using the **Releases** tab in **Azure DevOps** web console, to create release definitions, the tasks can resolve `$(Release.ReleaseId)` inside of a bash task.

But if I instead do my deployment in the azure-pipelines.yml file and do `echo $(Release.ReleaseId)`, I get null because the variable doesn't exist. How come?

Here is part of the yml file

```
- stage: Deploy
dependsOn: BuildAndPublishArtifact
condition: succeeded('BuildAndPublishArtifact')
jobs:
- deployment: DeployToAWSDev
  displayName: My display name
  pool:
    vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
  environment: 'dev'
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - download: current
          artifact: MyArtifact

        - task: Base@3
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              echo $(Release.ReleaseId) # Nothing
```

Thanks for any help to point in the right direction of how I can retrieve my release id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) on variables. There's no differentiation of "build" vs "release" in a YAML pipeline. Thus, `Build.BuildId` would be the run's ID.